# Cannot GET /login on reload pages Angular 8 - Refused to load the image '/favicon.ico' because it violates the following Content Security Policy

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, angular8, content-security-policy

Getting this error Cannot GET login/ on the page body. How to fix this error in latest angular 8 app. I have tried all the solutions from the forums but no luck. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Please note no compilation errors in `ng serve, ng biuld --prod`. Below is the chrome console error. This error occurs only on the server url not in localhost.

> Refused to load the image 'serverUrL/favicon.ico' because it
>   violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src
>   'none'". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src'
>   is used as a fallback.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

**Method 1**

- Clean cache (npm cache clean --force)
- Delete node_modules folder (rm -rf node_modules)
- Delete package-lock.json file (rm -f package-lock.json)
- Do fresh install (npm install)

**Method 2**

- Update nodejs

**Method 3**

Update the following code within head section of index.html

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'
https://yourdomain.com;">
```

Content-Security-Policy (CSP)

CSP Directive: default-src

CSP value: ‘self’ (Restrict source to same origin)

*References*

[More at Github Angular repo](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/30802)

[About Content Security Policy](https://contentlab.io/what-web-developers-need-to-know-about-content-security-policy)